# Help with custom jQuery validation function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form attribute like so:

```
onsubmit="return valMyForm(this);"
```

And a jQuery function like so:

```
function valMyForm(f) {
  $(f,"input").each(function() {
      if($(this).length < 1) {
          alert("All Fields Required.");
          return false;
      }
          else
          return false;
  });
}
```

The form still submits even if I remove all of the code and just put `return false;`

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but the last `else` isn't necessary. ;-)

Comment: @Brad, thank you, I am always looking for shorter ways to write code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` inside the `each` function is just exiting out of the each loop. It's not returning the value for `valMyForm`

You should use something like a valid variable and return that:

```
function valMyForm(f) {
  var valid = true;
  $("input", f).each(function() {
      if($(this).val().length < 1) {
          alert("All Fields Required.");
          valid = false;
      }
  });

  return valid;
}
```

Here is a working example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/adpMT/

Comment: here's a demo of what I've come up with: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Unny3/1/ in case you're interested.

Comment: @Brad Christie - Ah, I actually just posted a fiddle for you in my answer

Comment: I think you're is best answer. I can't seem to get short-hand of `[value=""]` wot work from Darin's example. So +1 to you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When you return you are inside the `.each` function so you are not actually returning anything from the `valMyForm` method.

I would recommend you avoid mixing markup with javascript and do this unobtrusively:

```
<form action="/foo" id="myform">
   ... some input fields
</form>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        // see if the form contains some empty inputs
        return $(this).find(':input[value=""]').length > 0;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Darin: I may be wrong, and don't know how the function is being called, but I think the input selector needs to be reversed too, to: `$('input',f)`. But again, I don't know how the function's being called.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, ha it would help if I told it to check the length of the value.

Comment: @Brad, the form is passing my function a parameter of 'this'.

Comment: @nick: Brad is right. Your selector is looking for `f` within the context of all the `input` elements on the page. You should be looking for `input` elements in the context of `f`. `$('input',f)` or better `$(f).find('input')`

Comment: @Darin, the function works, as in it shows the alert box, but then when I hit ok it posts the form :(

Comment: @nick, what is the value of the `$(this).find('input[value=""]').length > 0` expression inside the submit event?

Comment: @patrickdw: `$('input',f)` is short-hand for `$(f).find('input')`, according to the jQuery docs. ;-) Also, @DarinDimitrov: +1 for the short-hand solution. ;-)

Comment: @Brad: Yep, I know. That's why `$(f).find('input')` is better. It doesn't need to run through a bunch of tests before it just flips it around and starts over. :o)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: It appears jQuery isn't fond of [value=""], at least in my tests...

Comment: @Brad, I did a mistake. The correct selector should be `var isValid = $(this).find(':input[value=""]').length < 1`. Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/whgXU/3/).